# Ansible include roles that have been defined in hostvars

Tags: roles, ansible

I am trying to do the following:

1. define appropriate host roles in hostvars
2. create a role to call ONLY the roles that relate to specific host and have been defined in a variable in hostvars

Is there a way to do this?

eg:

#### host_vars/hostname_one/mail.yml

```
roles_to_install:
  - role_one
  - role_two
  - ...
```

#### run_all_roles.yml

```
---
- hosts: '{{ TARGET }}'

  become: yes
  ... 
  roles:
    - { role: "roles_to_install"}
```

Obviously this does not work.

Is there a way to make `ansible-playbook -i <hosts_file> run_all_roles.yml -e "TARGET=hostname_one"` to run?

Comment: You could try `roles: "{{ roles_to_install }}"` but I doubt this will work.

Comment: Tried that did not work, why do you say that it will not work thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented the solution was easier than expected:

```
--- 
- hosts: '{{ TARGET }}' 
  become: yes 

  vars_files: 
  - ./vars/main.yml 

  roles: 
    - { role: "roleA", when: "'roleA' in roles_to_install" } 
    - { role: "roleB", when: "'roleB' in roles_to_install" } 
    ...
```

Assuming that a correct roles_to_install var is defined inside host_vars/$fqdn/main.yml like so:

```
---
roles_to_install:
  - roleA
  - roleB
  - ...
```

Thank you for you assistance guys

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you should be approaching your roles and inventories.

Instead, if you put your hosts in the inventory in appropriate groups you can use the `hosts` parameter of the playbook to drive what gets installed where.

For example I might have a typical web application that is running on NGINX with some application specific things (such as a Python environment), but is also fronted by some NGINX servers that may serve static content and there could also be a typical database.

My inventory might then look like this:

```
[frontend-web-nodes]
web-1.example.org
web-2.example.org

[application-nodes]
app-1.example.org
app-2.example.org

[database-nodes]
database.example.org
```

Now, I can create a playbook for my database role that goes and installs some database and configures and set `hosts: database-nodes` to make sure the play (and so the role(s) that it runs only targets the `database.example.org` box.

So something like this:

```
- name: database

  hosts: database-nodes

  roles:

    - database
```

For my frontend and application web nodes I have a shared dependency on installing and configuring NGINX but my application servers also need some other things. So my front end web nodes can be configured with a simple play like this:

```
- name: frontend-web

  hosts: frontend-web-nodes

  roles:

    - nginx
```

While for my application nodes I might either have something like this:

```
- name: application

  hosts: application-nodes

  roles:

    - nginx

    - application
```

Or I could just do this:

```
- name: application

  hosts: application-nodes

  roles:

    - application
```

And in my `roles/application/meta/main.yml` define a [dependency](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies) on the nginx role:

```
dependencies:
  - role: nginx
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am trying to assign roles according to variables set inside host_vars/hostname_one/main.yml and host_vars/hostname_two/main.yml. Basically I want installed according to what I have in host_vars.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that. And as mentioned that's not how Ansible is meant to be used

Comment: The solution was simpler than that and I assume ansible provides for it :    ```
  ---
- hosts: '{{ TARGET }}'
  become: yes

  vars_files:
    - ./vars/main.yml

  roles:
    - { role: "roleA", when: "'roleA' in roles_to_install" }
    - { role: "roleB", when: "'roleB' in roles_to_install" }
    ...

    ``` using when...in we solve the issue. Thank you guys for your help...

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

**playfile.yml:**

```
- hosts:  all
  tasks:
    - when: host_roles is defined
      include_role:
        name:       "{{ role_item }}"
      loop:         "{{ host_roles }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var:   role_item
```

**hostvars_file.yml:**

```
host_roles:
  - name: myrole1
    myrole1_var1:     "myrole1_value1"
    myrole1_var2:     "myrole1_value2"                

  - name: myrole2
    myrole2_var1:     "myrole2_value1"
    myrole2_var2:     "myrole2_value2"
```

but then your *hostvar_roles* would be run during task-execution, normally roles will be executed before tasks.

Alternativly why dont have a role for this:

**roles/ansible.hostroles/tasks/main.yml:**

```
---
# tasks file for ansible.hostroles

- when: host_roles is defined
  include_role:
    name:       "{{ role_item }}"
  loop:         "{{ host_roles }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var:   role_item
```

**playfile.yml:**

```
- hosts:  all
  roles:
    - ansible.hostroles
```